# How to make 2 clients connect each other directly in c/c++, after having both connected to server?

Tags: sockets

Every info received by the server from the firstly-connected "client" A will be sent to the secondly-connected client B, even if A and B don't know their respective IP:

```
A -----------> server <----------- B     # they both connect the server first
A --"hello"--> server                    # A sends a message to server
               server --"hello"--> B     # the server sends the message to B
```

Comment: Are you asking how to bypass the server so that you can send data directly from A to B, or are you asking how to forward traffic through the server (e.g. A-->server-->B) ?

Comment: I want to implement client to client communication through server in C/C++. It will be fine if the traffic forward through server.

Comment: In that case you'll need a server that knows to read data from client connection A and forward it on to client connection B.  You can write a server like that yourself if you want, or you can find a pre-written one that will do that for you.  I wrote one that works well for me, you're welcome to use it if you like:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/

Comment: Client A needs to send a message to the server indicating what data to forward and who to forward it to (client B).  The server can then lookup the connection for that target client and send the data over that connection. That means the server needs to keep track of which connections are connected to it, and who they belong to. Have you tried implementing that much yet?